# Ввода массива в несколько строк

Tags: python

Пользователь изначально вводит размер массива
На основе этого я создаю нулевую матрицу.

```
line, column = input().split()
matrix = np.zeros((int(line), int(column)), dtype=int)
```

Нужно далее заполнить этот массив. Но ввод должен быть не по одному элементу, а строками

```
user input 7 2 8 9 5
user input 5 6 2 1 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

line, column = input().split()
matrix = np.zeros((int(line), int(column)), dtype=int)

for i in range(int(line)):
    for (j, el) in enumerate(input().split()):
        matrix[i][j] = el

print(matrix)
```